# determine whether user clicked NO in UAC prompt

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

My VBScript file:

```
    If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then

            Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            objShellApp.ShellExecute(WScript.FullName, WScript.ScriptFullName & " /elevate", "", "runas", 0)
            WScript.Quit 2
            WScript.Echo("Done 1")
        Else
```

I need a way to determine, whether the user clicked NO and then return an errorcode to a batch file. Does ShellExecute return any error codes or something?

The problem is that the errorcode returned to the bat is always the same (in this case 2), regardless of whether I clicked yes or no.

EDIT:

```
Dim objShell, objWMIService, servSpooler, objReg, objShellApp, result, oShell
    Dim whoami, strWhoamiOutput, whoamiOutput

    Const PrinterPort = "NUL:"
    Const HKLM = &h80000002

    If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then

        Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        objShellApp.ShellExecute WScript.FullName, WScript.ScriptFullName & " /elevate", "", "runas", 0
        WScript.Quit 10
        WScript.Echo("Done 1")

    Else

        Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set whoami = oShell.Exec("whoami /groups")
        Set whoamiOutput = whoami.StdOut
        strWhoamiOutput = whoamiOutput.ReadAll

        If InStr(1, strWhoamiOutput, "S-1-16-12288", vbTextCompare) Then
            Wscript.Echo("ADMIN")

            WScript.Echo("Port")
            Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
            set servSpooler = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Service.Name='spooler'")
            Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:root\default:StdRegProv")

            servSpooler.StopService

            objReg.SetStringValue HKLM, "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Ports", PrinterPort, ""

            servSpooler.StartService

            WScript.Quit 1

        End if
        WScript.Echo("Done 2")

    End If
    WScript.Quit 2
    WScript.Echo("Done 3")
```

It only ever returns the errorcode of the very first WScript.Quit, after getting the elevating rights. No matter whether I click no or yes. When I click yes, it runs the program as expected, and it does quit after starting the spooler, but the error code returned to the batch is still that of the first Wscript.Quit and not the one after the spooler.

I expect this to run as follows:

1. no elevated rights
2. get the elevation, if no, Quit with 10
3. if user clicked yes: run the script again
4. run the code in the ELSE block, quit with WScript.Quit 1
5. the code after the END IFs should never run

EDIT:

```
    If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
        Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        objShellApp.ShellExecute WScript.FullName, WScript.ScriptFullName & " /elevate", "", "runas", 0
        WScript.Quit 10
        WScript.Echo("Done 1")

    Else
Dim fso, MyFile
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile("testfile.txt", True)
   MyFile.WriteLine("This is a test.")
   MyFile.Close

    End If
    WScript.Quit 2
    WScript.Echo("Done 3")
```

When I run this from .../System32 it lets me create a file when I click yes. Still, the errorcode is always the same, whether I click yes or no.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a file in c:\windows\system32 and test the error code.

Only a program marked RequireAdmin will fail when executed. Everything else will start as a limited user.

For your method.

Return Value

```
No return value.
```

WScript has a two execute methods. Both have different features so read the docs.

```
object.Exec(strCommand)
```

The Exec method returns a WshScriptExec object, which provides status and error information about a script run with Exec along with access to the StdIn, StdOut, and StdErr channels.

```
object.Run(strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn])
```

bWaitOnReturn 
Optional. Boolean value indicating whether the script should wait for the program to finish executing before continuing to the next statement in your script. If set to true, script execution halts until the program finishes, and Run returns any error code returned by the program. If set to false (the default), the Run method returns immediately after starting the program, automatically returning 0 (not to be interpreted as an error code).

Comment: Okay, so ShellExecute definitely has no return value. As for the other to: I can't use them because then I cannot give the script elevated rights. I ran the whole thing from System32: same problem: It always returns the same errorcode. See my edit.

Comment: Try to create a file in system32. If unelevated the file create will fail with Access Denied (5 or 0x80070005 or 2147942405). The services commands doesn't require elevation so there's no error starting it. The only way you can tell if elevated or not is to try something that requires elevation. You can try a privledge comparision of `whoamI /all` PS: Also `wshshell.regwrite` is easier than wmi. Try starting your script in a debugger, one may be installed `cscript //x yourscript.vbs`

Comment: Okay, I tried it, see edit (hope I understood you correctly). And another thing: stopping and starting the spooler may not require elevated rights, but setting the reg key does, doesn't it? I get a UAC prompt when I open regedit, as well, and I'm admin. My problem isn't really the service command, it's the fact that the error code returned to the bat is always that of the first time I call the script.

Comment: That's because limited users can do somethings, they can often list. Just because a program needs admin permissions to do things doesn't mean it won't run. It just won't do what it's supposed to. The only time a program displays the elevation dialog and will refuse to run if if the manifest says  `level="requireAdministrator"`. If not or no manifest the program will happily run.

Comment: All you have to do is create a file in c:\windows\system32. That will tell you if you are admin.

Comment: When I rightclick and then go to "new" I can only create folders. the script is supposed to be executed by others on their machine. And if they're not admin and they double click on the file and then click NO in the UAC prompt, and thus the registry key is not created, they should be presented some kind of error message.

Comment: SO TRY AND CREATE A FILE IN C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32. That will tell you. This is the FIFTH time I've said this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it :D Do you mean "right click - new - text file"? like creating a new textfile on the desktop? If so, I tried that and I can't. The only thing it let's me create are folders.

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is that your code is not written correctly.

You must have `On Error Resume Next` or your script would have crashed. You use this statement for simple scripts that you want to keep going in case of error. In real scripts it indicates you are handling errors rather than vbs. So you need to code like this.

```
servSpooler.StartService
If err.number <> 0 then
    'print error, exit script
    wscript.echo err.number & " " & err.description & " in " & err.source
    err.clear
    wscript.quit
End If
```

But if you use vbs error handling it knows the line and column number.

Answer (score 0):

**Noooooooo** - create the file in code.

```
On Error Resume Next
'Should fail for everyone so simulates being a user for an admin
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.CreateTextFile "C:\System Volume Information\test.txt", vbtrue

msgbox err.number & " " & err.description & " " & err.source
If err.number = 70 then
    msgbox "access denied - not an admin"
    err.clear
Elseif err.number <> 0 then
    Msgbox "Unspecified error"
    err.clear
Else
    Msgbox "Is an admin"
End If

'Should succeed for admins
fso.CreateTextFile "c:\windows\system32\test.txt", vbtrue
msgbox err.number & " " & err.description & " " & err.source
If err.number = 70 then
    msgbox "access denied - not an admin"
    err.clear
Elseif err.number <> 0 then
    Msgbox "Unspecified error"
    err.clear
Else
    Msgbox "Is an admin"
End If
```

Comment: I'm loath to write your script for you. You are at work, I'm not. You haven't done exactly what I said to do. It seems you are a programmer without a model of how programs work. You need to start reading the documentation for each function you use and you need to browse the docs for fun. Also read the vbs articles here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/vbscript/. You need to understand COM Automation. Most of all you need to understand the basic structure of the Win32API, which is how programs work - vbs may see events but what is happening is messages.

Comment: Try puuting your commands into MY if blocks in the second block of code above.